# Why I am getting the "! File ended while scanning use of \backgroundsetup . <inserted text>\par<>

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I face error while compiling the following code would you help me please?

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\backgroundsetup{
    scale=.8,   
    angle=0, 
    firstpage = true,
    opacity=0.1, color=black,
    contents={\begin{tikzpicture[remember picture,overlay]
\node at ([yshift=10pt,xshift=10pt] current page.center){\includegraphics[width=5cm]{aait_logo}}}};
end{tikzpicture}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are several brace errors in the `contents` field, at least a missing one after `\begin{tikzpicture` and extra ones after `{aait_logo}`

Answer (score 1):

As @siracusa mentioned, there are problems with braces.  You have missing or misplaced `{` or `}`.  Additionally, you are missing a backslash for `end{tikzpicture}` which should be `\end{tikzpicture}`.  Because of the braces, the semicolon `;` is also in the wrong position.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
    scale=0.8,   
    angle=0, 
    firstpage=true,
    opacity=0.1,
    color=black,
    contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                \node at ([yshift=10pt,xshift=10pt] current page.center){%
                    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{aait_logo}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            }
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```